# Drawing the Tropics on D3.js geojson using Linestring

Tags: geojson, linestring, d3

I am using the geoMercator projection on D3.js and want to draw the Tropic of Cancer and Tropic of Capricorn on my map.

Right now I added the Equator using

```
plot.append("path")
  .datum({type: "LineString", coordinates: [[-180, 0], [-90, 0], [0, 0], [90, 0], [180, 0]]})
  .attr("class", "equator")
  .attr("d", path)
```

I tried adding this code for adding the data to draw the Tropic of Cancer at 23.43687 degrees

```
{type: "LineString", coordinates: [[-180, 23.43687],[180, 23.43687]]}
```

It works on [Geojosnlint.com](http://geojsonlint.com/) but not in D3. Also tried adding more points in the coordinates but the line was curved.

```
{type: "LineString", coordinates: [[-180, 23.43687],[90, 23.43687],[180, 23.43687]]}
```

How would I add a line that goes straight across?